# Software for displaying subtitles for audio files

Tags: audio, recording, language, subtitles

I am translating English speech to Russian, but I am not too experienced to speak Russian while listening to an English file of 40 minutes length, so I need a little preparation.

My plan is: Prepare Russian text and attach different Russian sentences to different parts of an English audio file. Then I start recording simultaneously with playing the English file *with* the subtitles attached to it.

Doing that, I will be able to see my Russian hints when listening to English speech.

Linux would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

For creating and displaying subtitles for an audio file you can use various subtitle software. One that should work for your needs is "Gnome Subtitles".

There you can choose Video/Open from the menu and select your audio file. It displays a video area above the subtitle definitions. For testing put some subtitle at say 2 seconds from the beginning and then use the play button in the video area. It plays the audio file and shows your subtitle after 2 seconds.

Of course, this is not a recording program. But you can just start the recording in another program (and adjust the pause at the beginning afterwards using an audio editing program. You will need one anyway, because 40 minutes is long enough that you would want to put together sentences from different recordings.)

Comment: However I do not quite understand why you want to hear the English text while recording. It is a big distraction. For movie dubbing you would have to pay attention on timing but better use the images with lip movements for orientation. For a pure audio file it makes more sense to translate the text and read out / record it, completely ignoring the timing of the original.

Comment: I would like to sound syncronically with english speaker :)

Comment: Ok, I guess it is some art project :) Anyway, did my suggestion work for you?

Comment: I developed my own software for this :)